# Hard Disk Identification of SATA Hard Disk (generic), SSD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, nvme, sata, secure-erase

I need to secure erase the following drive types:

1. SSD Disk >>> hdparm <<< If there is a better tool /approach, please let me know.
2. Hard Disk >>> shred /scrub /nwipe

Is it possible to detect the disk type dynamically (with some script) to automate the erase process?
I will be booting the machine with a Ubuntu USB stick (the script should NOT erase this boot USB stick).

Comment: Just so you know, having an automated (dumb) script/process/program that blindly shreds an entire medium is a fundamentally bad idea.  Should you get what you are asking for I suspect you will be back asking how to restore an "accidentally" shredded device.

Comment: Most HDDs can also be erased by `hdparm` (like SSDs) by rearranging the mapping between logical and physical locations of the memory cells. This is very reliable, faster than overwriting (typically by shread) and causes less wear. [This link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2124829) is a bit old, the syntax of the hdparm command line may have changed, but it may still be useful. Please read the current `man hdparm' very carefully, and *do not use the method for drives connected via USB*..

Comment: What do you mean by 'detect the disk type dynamically (with some script)'? Do you mean to get the device name (to find letter `x` in `/dev/sdx` for SATA drives or numbers `i` and `j` in `/dev/nvmeinj` for nvme drives)? You can use `lsblk` ( with options and treat its output) in the script for that purpose.

Comment: @sudodus 
With dynamic detection I meant if the PC hard disk is convention hard disk or SSD. 
And if the disk is SSH, clean it using hdparm otherwise, the disk is non-SSD, use Shred or DoD etc.

Comment: @user1737015, I see. Maybe `lsblk ...` would work for you, see for example `lsblk -e7 -d -o model,name,size,rota,type`. On the other hand, what I tried to tell you before, is that hdparm is good also for mechanical HDDs.

Comment: @sudodus and if I understood you correctly, you mean hdparm can be used for both SSDs and sequential disk types. 
How about the DoD 3 pass or DoD 7 pass? These standard will cause "wear" if used on the SSD drives. Reason why I am asking is to use something which is "standardized" like DoD or Gutman etc.
Note: Asking only for the SSD and NVMe drives.

Comment: Yes, hdparm can be used for both SSDs and rotating devices (hard disk drives). Overwriting several times is slow and causes wear. The wear is extra serious on solid state devices, USB pendrives, memory cards and SSDs. Anyway, use what gives you peace of mind. If you don't rely on hdparm for HDDs, use some overwriting method. But I strongly recommend the hdparm method for SSDs (both connected via SATA and NVME).

Comment: @sudodus thanks for reply.
No, it's not about peace of mind, I asked for due to the "standard", otherwise, I have no concerns.
a.  So should I rule out now that DoD 3 pass can be used on SSD and NVM as well but there is a risk of wear.?

b. You mentioned hdparm for NVME as well, however, I have considered the NVM-CLI for the NVM drives. 
Can we use hdparm on HD, SSD and NVME?

Comment: It is a good alternative to use `sudo nvme format -s1 <device>` (from the package nvme-cli) for nvme drives. There ***is*** wear (not risk of wear) when overwriting, but you must rely on the proprietary built-in tools in SATA and NVME drives for 'hdparm' and 'nvme format -s1'  to work.

Comment: @sudodus, thanks. 
the lsblk command you provided with the output "rota" is useful. This tells me if the  drive is rotational or not. Now I can proceed further if rota=0 it's SSD, otherwise HDD.